# How to notify Facebook that my mobile application was installed?

Tags: facebook, mobile, ads, facebook-marketing-api

I'm developing a game in Unreal, for iOS and Android, I'd like to know how is it possible to inform Facebook every time that the app is installed on a new device. It would help in ads for the future.
The Facebook documentation is confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out it! We need to use Facebook Events by adding the Facebook SDK for Android and iOS. The events of app install, app launch will be logged automatically for Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events